# Why does building the parachain template build the polkadot and kusama runtime?

Tags: substrate-parachain-template, compilation

This is on my screen as I compile the substrate parachain template:

```
Building: kusama-runtime(build), polkadot-runtime(build), parachain-template-runtime(build)
```

Why does it need to build the kusama and polkadot runtime for a parachain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could figure out this yourself.

Just check the lock file.

Let's take parachain-template as an example.

1. search `polkadot-runtime`
2. found `polkadot-service` depends on `polkadot-runtime`
3. search `polkadot-service`
4. found `cumulus-relay-chain-inprocess-interface` depends on `polkadot-service`
5. search `cumulus-relay-chain-inprocess-interface`
6. found `parachain-template-node` depends on `cumulus-relay-chain-inprocess-interface`

That's it.

---

https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template/blob/677a1a238a9592d0c8f1f0a4b7477b031da76c20/Cargo.lock#L6158

Answer (score 1):

From the protocol perspective; due to polkadot's shared security the parachain's finalized state is guaranteed on the relay chain. In other words, information regarding a parachain block, whether it is included, reverted or finalized, is acquired from the relay chain. In order to obtain and verify the latest information about blocks and finality a parachain needs to be in sync with the relay chain (networking, consensus, finality, etc). For this reason a parachain node also consists of a relay chain client (e.g. polkadot or kusama).